# How can I add data to Firebase database?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I think I wrote the codes correctly, but Firebase does not add data in Realtime Database. I downloaded the JSON file, connected the project, checked it via Firebase tools, but it still doesn't add data. What can I do it?

Mainactivity.java - addevent class(it will work when click the button)

```
private void addEvent(){
    String plan =  etplan.getText().toString();
    String note =  etnote.getText().toString();
    String date =  etdate.getText().toString();
    String time =  ettime.getText().toString();
    String remb = "false";
    if (remember.isChecked()==true){
        remb = "true";
    }
    else{
        remb = "false";
    }
    String id = dbRef.push().getKey();
    Events event = new Events(id,plan,note,date,time,remb);
    dbRef.child(id).setValue(event);
}
```

I get the following error in the Run section of the program:

```
glUtilsParamSize: unknow param at 0x000082
```

And edited this code:

```
dbRef.child(id).setValue(event)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Events Added SUCCESSFULLY!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're not checking the result of the call to setValue.  It could be failing.  I suggest reviewing the documentation on that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited this code but I can't see any error but "glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da" saw this from Run. I can't understand

Comment: @DougStevenson hello. I solved this problem. I editted from Virtual Device Configuration  -> Graphics -> "automatic" switched to "SOFTWARE" and restarted my emulator and added value. Thanks for helping.  I'm sorry if I kept you busy.

Comment: That error message is not at all related to Firebase though.  It shouldn't in any way affect the way the code runs.